# Tabbing to First Element when react-virtualized is scrolled to the bottom

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, tabindex, react-virtualized

I am using [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/List.md) library. And I need to be able to tab through the list.

Since not all the items are rendered, I am not able to tab to the **last row**

Similar issue will happen if I want to tab to the **first row** when **virtual list is scrolled to the bottom of the list**

If I was able to **always render first row and last** row, no matter scrolling position, I would be able to tab to the **last** and **first** element.

**Use case:**

Imagine current focus is on input box which is situated above the virtual list, and imagine virtual list is scrolled to the bottom.

If I press on my keyboard tab I expect my focus to be on the first element. But because the first element is not rendered,the focus will be on the first rendered row by virtual list. I hope this makes sense.

**This is my current code:**

```
class Locations extends React.Component {

  setListElementRef = (ref) => {
    this.listRef = ref;
  }

  rowRenderer = ({ index, style }) => {
    return (
      <div style={style} key={index} >
        <CheckBoxContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const {
      filteredLocations, onSearchValueChange,
    } = this.props;

    return (
          <List
            tabIndex={-1}
            isScrollingOptOut
            ref={this.setListElementRef}
            rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
            rowCount={filteredLocations.length}
            rowHeight={32}
            height={300}
            width={218}
            overscanRowCount={5}
          />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Why aren't all rows rendered? Are they loaded only on scroll? In that case, would the question be how to make a lazy-loading-list accessible for keyboard? I don't know why only first and last are an issue, and not those in between, if you use tab.

Comment: Are you aware of the [ARIA keyboard pattern for grids](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#grid)? In long lists TAB is not very practical, hence the arrow keys should be used, along with POS1 and END to jump to start or end of the list/grid.

Comment: @Andy Sorry I have to use tabbing.
The rendering of first and last element, will help me to jump to the first and last element when tabbing. I would scroll the element into view when it is focused.

Comment: @Andy because its a virtual list, only visible part is rendered

Comment: Wouldn't scrolling the focussed element into view result in the rendering of more elements? Hence you'll end up at the top and the bottom somewhen?

Comment: @Andy imagine current focus is on  input box which is situated above the virtual list, and imagine virtual list is scrolled to the bottom. if I press on my keyboard `tab` I expect my focus to be on the first element. But because the first element is not rendered, instead the focus will be on the first rendered row by virtual list. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. You stated in your question that you cannot tab to the **last row**. This is wrong then, I guess? Would forcing render on `focusin` be an option?

Comment: How do you force render?